# Is there an efficient R function to generate a dataframe from a function?

Tags: r, dataframe, functional-programming

I want to generate a dataframe where each row is given by a function of the cross product of several properties.
This can be done imperatively:

```
seed <- expand.grid(
  c(1,2,3), 
  c(4,5,6)
)
d <- data.frame() 
for(i in 1:nrow(seed)) {
  d[i,"prop1"] = f(seed[i,])
  d[i,"prop2"] = g(seed[i,])
}
```

where `f` and `g` are functions. But I would prefer a functional version. I tried to use `pmap`:

```
pmap(seed, ~ data.frame(
  prop1 = f(..1, ..2), 
  prop2 = g(..1, ..2))
)
```

but this doesn't give me a dataframe. Is there an (efficient) way to do this without loops?

Comment: What do `f` and `g` do?

Comment: Your best option is replacing these functions by some clever matrix algebra. I don't know if that is possible here because you haven't shared the functions.

Comment: f and g are arbitrary functions without side-effects that return a single value. I need a solution where their inner structure doesn't matter.

Comment: The more you constrain a problem, the more efficient the solution can be. For arbitrary functions, there is only so much you can do with an interpreted language. R already has JIT byte compilation active by default. It you are not willing to constrain this more,  I believe you are out of luck if you aren't willing to optimize your functions' implementation and ideally implement your functions in Rcpp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `f` and `g` return atomic values to populate dataframe `d`, why not just return the complete vectors instead by passing `seed` to the functions?  E.g.

```
d$prop1 <- f(seed)
d$prop2 <- g(seed)
```

Comment: Image `f` being something like `sum`. For `sum` we have `rowSums` but there is no efficient solution for an arbitrary function like that.

Comment: If `f(seed[i, ])` returns a single value, then update `f` to accept `seed` as the parameter and process all `i` in the function itself, store as a vector and return the vector.  Am I missing something?